# how to rank user's list of interests

Tags: java, mongodb, machine-learning

I have a list of user interests marked with numbers.

Every user has several interests. How do I compose a number that represent the user's interests so I'll be able to find other users with similar or close interests in a simple MongoDB query.

Comment: You don't. There is no "simple" MongoDB query for this nor is there a schema that allows you to convert this problem into a simple query. It's basically n-vector comparison you're looking for so you'll need to build/find a search engine that does that.

Comment: You can provided you have some locality sensitive hashing as signatures for user's interests and do bucketing on those signatures. When you want to find similar users for a specific user `A`, you get all users in every bucket that `A` belongs to. I can write some details later. But in short, you need locality sensitive hashing constructed to avoid the n-vector comparison at query-time.

Answer (score 2):

When there are *n* different interests, each user can be represented as a length-*n* vector of booleans where the *i*'th element is true iff the user has listed interest *i*. Two such vectors can be compared with cosine similarity, [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), L1 distance, L2 distance, etc.

Comment: Thank.
The number of interests is not known in advance so i cant represented as boolean vector, is there way to that when the number of interests change

Comment: @shai: the vectors are primarily conceptual; you can represent them any way you want if you just follow the appropriate formulas. Note in particular that distances between two vectors don't change when you append an equal number of zeros to both, so if you really use boolean vectors, then you can always append zeros later without affecting previous results.

Answer (score 1):

No idea how do it directly with MongoDB, but if you have "biginteger" datatype, then reduce the interests to a bitfield. You can't then remove interestes (without recalculating bitfield for everybody), but you can add interestes, since having them selected will just add more bits to the biginteger. Then to compare interestes of persons A and B, you have operations, in C/C++ like syntax:

- `common=bitCount(A&B)` how many common interests A and B have
- `onlyA=bitCount(A^(A&B))` how many interests A has, that B does not have
- `onlyB=bitCount(B^(A&B))` how many interests B has, that A does not have
- `different=bitCount(A^B)` how many different interests A and B have total (same as onlyA+onlyB)
- `total=bitCount(A|B)` how many different interests A and B have total (same as common+different)

From these numbers you can evaluate how closely the interests match, exact formula depending on how you want to emphasize same interestes vs. different interests and what scale you want to have.

At least Java's BigInteger class has bit counting method out-of-the-box, otherwise it can be done with brute-force loop using &1 and >>1 operations. Don't know if MongoDB supports such constructs or has operator/function for bit count of a big int data, or even if MongoDB has big int data type...

Answer (score 0):

I could probably try to do this in following way

1. I will have all the interests part of columns of a database.
2. For every user, every column will have a value 0 or 1.
3. To find if 2 usershave close interests, I will retrieve the values
   of interests from DB and store in a domainObject (which has fields
   for each interest (column).Then I will implement a comparator which
   will update a int field based on the number of matching columns.
4. Based on this number I can decide on a logic , sa for example if
   total interest is 10 and matches > 7 then it is close, else not
   close etc.